# "failed to spawn server object" error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I did the Unity Networking Tutorial at https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking, then added the Network Lobby from the Unity Technologies assets.

However, after setting up the asset, the bullets are not shown on the client side. I also get a "Failed to spawn server object, did you forget to add it to the Network Manager?" error on the client side.

I added the bullets to the network manager and it still doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using two different projects to build the server and client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found my answer. After doing some digging I found out that you have to register the prefabs in the lobby manager.

Here is the original answer. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1295343/unet-networkserverspawn-not-working-failed-to-spaw.html